# Where's my screen when I'm running a Selenium scraper from Scheduled Tasks?

Tags: c#, google-chrome, azure, selenium, screen-scraping

Context: Azure; C#; .NET 4.5.2; Selenium 2.53

I'm running a Selenium-based scraper written in C# from a Scheduled Task. ChromeDriver.exe runs silently and launches Chrome.exe silently: neither interact with the logged-on user's screen.

I've been asked to make a video of the interaction between the C# app, ChromeDriver and Chrome. It's proving to be a bit harder than I thought.

I've tried Screencastify on the expectation that, because it's running as a Chrome extension, that it would "see" the screen and thus be able to record it. However, Screencastify is proving to be quite hard to drive, not least because I'm having to send keystrokes to it rather than being able to control it via an API.

I noticed that Screencastify does have an API but that using it presupposes that you've got it installed in your own site. That is, it's not scraper friendly.

There are other screen capture tools out there like [ScreenRecorder](http://chehraz.ir/projects/screenrecorder/). I'm not at all sure if it will work in this situation, there being no screen as such (unless one launches it with the scraper.)

In this situation is Chrome just doing something within itself and ignoring the lack of an output device? That is, is it running in a kind of pseudo-headless-browser state?

Is making a video of a scheduled scrape by definition impossible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set the task to only run when the user is logged in otherwise it will start hidden and you won't be able to see it. Also make sure hidden isn't checked. You can set a default user to login when the machine starts and then have the task kick off when that user is logged in. That way everything will be visible on the desktop.

[image: Task Scheduler]